# How to retrieve all ERC721 tokens of a certain collection what a wallet ownes?

Tags: ethers.js, nft, erc-721

Suppose, I have ERC721 NFT collection. And I sell it via my website.

When a user comes, logs in via MetaMask, how will I be able to retrieve all of the NFTs of **my collection** that he owns? Will I at all?

**Without the likes of Moralis, Alchemy. Only in pure ethers.js**

Answer (score 2):

In order to do it without using the likes of Moralis. You need:

1. An RPC node
2. The contract address
3. The wallet address
4. The contract ABI

Then you can write a function like this:

```
async function getNFTsOfOwner() {
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, erc721ABI, provider);
  const balance = await contract.balanceOf(ownerAddress); //Returns the number of tokens owned by the address

  let tokenIds = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < balance.toNumber(); i++) {
    const tokenId = await contract.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(ownerAddress, i); //Get the token ID based on the index from the balanceOf call
    tokenIds.push(tokenId.toString());
  }

  console.log(`Token IDs owned by ${ownerAddress}: ${tokenIds}`);
}
```

At the end of this, you will have all token IDs in the `tokenIds` array. If you want the metadata for the tokens you're going to need to call the `tokenURI()` function for each token ID, call the URI and retrieve the metadata for each token.

It's quite a lot of work but definitely doable. If you do change your mind here is how you would do it with the Moralis [getWalletNFTs](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/reference/get-wallet-nfts) endpoint.

```
const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.nft.getWalletNFTs({
    "chain": "0x1",
    "format": "decimal",
    "tokenAddresses": [
      "INSERT COLLECTION ADDRESS"
    ],
    "mediaItems": false,
    "address": "0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045"
  });
```

This would give you all NFTs with all the metadata, attributes and images directly in the response.

Disclaimer, I work at Moralis.

Comment: Ok, I'll use Alchemy.com then

Answer (score 0):

ethers.js simply queries the calling contract, and only gets the status of a known contract in a certain block. The token type owned by an account must be provided by etherscan or a third-party query to record your transaction records.

Comment: What "token type"?

Comment: But how does your post answer my question?